# Azure Service Bus, one push results in 300 queued messages with the same ID

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure function which I just updated to look like this:

public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("xxxx", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = true)] Message message, ILogger log, IMessageSession messageSession)

I did this so I could do this:

```
    var rec = messageSession as MessageReceiver;

    if(rec != null)
    {
        rec.RetryPolicy = Microsoft.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.NoRetry;
    }

    _event.PushEvent(new Event
    {
        EventName = $"{message.MessageId} - {message.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount}",
        EventData = string.Empty,
        DateOfEvent = DateTime.Now, 
        EventLevel = 1,
        System = Systems.CRMSQL
    }).Wait();
    
    // Manually close message so it won't requeue
    messageSession.CloseAsync().Wait();
```

My event logging is showing the same message being processed over and over

```
    EventName EventData EventLevel DateOfEvent
    5f353e313f104c298bdffa08030d9daa - 1 1 2020-09-03 01:17:47.903
    5f353e313f104c298bdffa08030d9daa - 1 1 2020-09-03 01:17:46.083
    5f353e313f104c298bdffa08030d9daa - 1 1 2020-09-03 01:17:45.227
```

Why is my function pulling the same message over and over, without the delivery count increasing, even though I am manually closing the message? It did this before I added this code, this is the issue I was trying to resolve.

My logs confirm we called the function to push into the service bus once. I log pushing as an event, there is one event log.  The graph in Azure shows a jagged climb to 300 messages in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

> // Manually close message so it won't requeue
> messageSession.CloseAsync().Wait()

The function will automatically complete the incoming message once it's done. If you're closing the receiver before incoming message was completed, the message will be redelivered `maxDeliveryCount` times and you'll see duplicates.

Not sure what `_event.PushEvent` is, but if it's your code, you should elaborate what it does. Additionally, don't force asynchronous code to run with `.Wait()`. Rather use `async/await`.

Comment: It pushes an event to the DB.  I had max retry set to 10 and I was getting the same message id, with a DeliveryCount of 1, 400 times.  I've changed my code, it's not actually closing the message.  This is an integration piece and my code was calling CRM for more than 5 mintues, so I am hoping manually closing the message at the start will stop it repeating, I'll be testing it again tomorrow.

Comment: Message is not closed. It should be completed. You were closing the connection breather than completing the message manually. It's possible to complete the message manually, but you'd need to configure the function via `host.json`.